# Tensorflow model.fit() returns NaN with all float input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to run a regression model very similar to the Tensorflow tutorial (with my own dataset). My data and labels are `float` values in numpy arrays, e.g.:

Data, varname `input_array`:

```
[[0.63473794 0.16736857 0.19028714 1.38746357 1.00389089 1.78771353]
 [0.58772032 0.19225393 0.22888241 1.41612279 1.09661261 1.52805896]
 [0.37530531 0.19501039 0.24683006 1.31084661 1.14897087 0.86286696]
 [0.29121152 0.19009779 0.255342   1.16257489 1.16012728 0.1838582 ]]
```

Labels, varname `label_array`:

```
[[-0.00362812]
 [-0.00136054]
 [-0.00181653]
 [ 0.00136302]]
```

My model is built with:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=[len(input_array.keys())]),

layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
layers.Dense(1)
])
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=['mean_absolute_error', 'mean_squared_error'])
```

Training function is:

```
history = model.fit(
  input_array, label_array,
  epochs=EPOCHS, validation_split = 0.2, verbose=0,
  callbacks=[cp_callback])
```

For any number of epochs, the model returns:

```
   loss  mean_absolute_error  ...  val_mean_squared_error  epoch
0   NaN                  NaN  ...                     NaN      0
```

I'm not sure what non-number could be causing the problem, since all the values I gave the model are numbers.

Comment: Try using a Adam optimizer with a low learning rate like 0.0001. NaN is nothing but  Not A Number. Slow and steady training always helps if the network has a good speed of training.

Answer (score 1):

I've simplified the code a bit and it runs fine in colab.

```
from __future__ import print_function

from tensorflow.python import keras
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
import numpy as np

input_array = np.array([
 [0.63473794, 0.16736857, 0.19028714, 1.38746357, 1.00389089, 1.78771353],
 [0.58772032, 0.19225393, 0.22888241, 1.41612279, 1.09661261, 1.52805896],
 [0.37530531, 0.19501039, 0.24683006, 1.31084661, 1.14897087, 0.86286696],
 [0.29121152, 0.19009779, 0.255342,   1.16257489, 1.16012728, 0.1838582 ]])

label_array = np.array([
    [-0.00362812],
    [-0.00136054],
    [-0.00181653],
    [ 0.00136302]])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(input_array.shape[1],)))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='rmsprop', validation_split=0.25,
              metrics=['mean_absolute_error', 'mean_squared_error'])


model.fit(input_array, label_array, epochs=100)
```

In general, I find it useful to avoid mixing keras and tf APIs unless it is required. I understand that this doesn't exactly pin-point the problem with your code but I hope that it can be useful for you to move forward.